# mat-select with checkboxes

Tags: angular-material

I really want the mat-select basic functionality but with checkboxes.
If I turn on [multiple] I get the checkboxes but I also get multi-select functionality, I need single select and checkbox.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can achieve your requirements like this,

here's is example,

in `app.component.html`

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Toppings">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList; let i =index" [value]="topping">
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="selected === i" (change)="onChange(topping);selected = i"> {{topping}}</mat-checkbox>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in `app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent {
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage'];
  selected = -1;

  /*checkbox change event*/
  onChange(event) {
    console.log(event)
  }
}
```

here's is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7vtuj-wzezgy?file=app/select-multiple-example.ts) demo

Comment: i was getting frustrated with downvotes and no one responding to my posts unless I post a bounty, you've restored my faith in the site!

Comment: i did find 1 bug, you can click to the far right of an option and the option will change, but the checkmark will not update :(  bonus points if you know how to fix that!!  :)

Comment: Actually problem is that, people not interested to read theory question that's why without reading question they started downvotes, if you put some bit of code then they can help you.

Comment: And as you told me the issue, tommarow i will look into this and will try to fix it.

Comment: thanks for the help!!  and i figured out the last trick also!!  I had to make a few elements width: 100% and then override an inline-flex with an inline-block and now the options take the whole length and the checkbox and label still remain to the left.  THANKS FOR EVERYTHING!!!   :)    i will also be sure to include code

Comment: @AniketAvhad: I am trying to figure out how I can modify your example, so that more than one checkbox can be checked at a time. So far, no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: @ShawnSpencer - you can use "multiple" attibute on mat-select tag...here is a example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7vtuj-gk81ni?file=app/select-multiple-example.html

Comment: @AniketAvhad: Cool. Just what I had missed. However, in my code, this now also creates (or displays) a second check box next to each checkbox. I can hide them with (S)CSS, but it's odd that this would happen:
`<mat-pseudo-checkbox class="mat-option-pseudo-checkbox mat-pseudo-checkbox ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-state="" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></mat-pseudo-checkbox>`

Comment: is it possible to select more than one option like  chips  https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview

Answer (score 1):

#### This behavior now comes for 'free' in Angular 15 Material (for accessibility reasons).

Compare the following versions, and you'll see that for v15 and later, a checkbox appears after the text.

https://v15.material.angular.io/components/select/overview
https://v14.material.angular.io/components/select/overview

This can be disabled with the [`hideSingleSelectionIndicator`](https://v15.material.angular.io/components/select/overview#accessibility) option,

WARNING: If you have a small width select boxes (eg. for a simple quantity field) the checkbox can actually obscure the text itself. This just happened to me without realizing and I ended up with this monstrosity.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://v15.material.angular.io/components/select/examples#select-multiple

This link provide you direct access to the mat select with checkbox

Comment: The author specifically asked how to get checkboxes **without** multi selection, so this does not answer the question.